# (ConTeXt) Is it possible to use different paper orientation in the same document?

Tags: context

For example, I have two pages. I want the first to be portrait and the second landscape. Can I do that? Or I have to make two pdf and combine them as one later?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's trivial: just use the `\setuppapersize` command twice. The only thing to bear in mind is that issuing a `\setuppapersize` midway down a page changes the page it is ‘on’, not the next page.

You can also use `\adaptpapersize`  to change the paper size for one page only, and ConTeXt will automatically return to the previous paper size after that. [The wiki has an example.](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setuppapersize). Below is a simpler example of using `\setuppapersize` twice.

```
\setuppapersize[A8,landscape]

\starttext
\input knuth

% Putting \setuppapersize before \page would change the papersize one page too early.
% \setuppapersize[A8,portrait]
\page
\setuppapersize[A8,portrait]

asdf
\stoptext
```